# Proof that a function constant on 2 disjoint closed subsets of $\Bbb R$ with standard topology can be extended to continuos function on $\Bbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

I want to prove that function constant on 2 disjoint closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with standard topology can be extended to continuos function on $\mathbb{R}$.

My first attempt was to connect boundary points from disjoint subsets via line segments. That would work if there was a way to get next boundary point. Unfortunately there is no way to get next boundary point of a closed subset - they are too complex and closest border point may not even exists.

So completely another way of thinking should be used. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, at least one closest boundary point does exist for each $x$

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen can you please explain why that is true?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is closed and $x$ apoint, then the distance of $x$ from $A$ can be defined as $$d(x,A):=\inf\{\,|x-a|:a\in A\,\}$$
and is positive iff $x\notin A$. (It can be defined also if $A$ is not closed, but then it may be $0$ even for some $x\notin A$). Note that $d$ is continuous in $x$.
Now define
$$ f(x):=\frac{d(x,B)c_A+d(x,A)c_B}{d(x,A)+d(x,B)}.$$
Since $A,B$ are closed and disjoint, it is always guaranteed that the denominator is positive.

Comment: It almost perfect. Can you please provide formal arguments showing why $d$ is continuos?

Comment: @Hedgehog Continuity is straightforward from the triangle inequality, and does not even need that $A,B$ are closed (just that they are nonempty). Just show that $|d(x,B)-d(y,B)|\le|x-y|$ for any $x,y$, and similarly with $A$ in place of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you suggest is correct: Recall that the complement of a closed set is an open set and that any open set in $\mathbb R$ is the union of disjoint open intervals.

If $x$ is not in either closed set, then it is in one of these open intervals, whose endpoints belong to the closed sets. So you can indeed just use a straight line on the interval to extend the function. If the interval is unbounded, just make its value constantly equal to the value the function takes on the other endpoint.